# Run_simple dev web server from werkzeug does not run using reloader under Windows

Tags: python, windows, werkzeug

I can not run the `run_simple` dev web server from werkzeug under windows *and* `use_reloader=True` :

```
run_simple("localhost", 8090, application, use_reloader=True)
```

Eventually it throws `too many values to unpack` while traversing `new_environ` in `wergzeug.serving`. If I remove `use_reloader` (defaults to `False`) than the server runs without problems. What do I miss?

**UPDATE**: This problem appears only on 0.6 version. (That is, on 0.5 works, on 0.6 it does not. I don't know about the minor revisions.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the development version.  The upcoming 0.7 release will fix that.